# Sylow subgroup of symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

I just read that any sylow subgroup of S20 is a subset of A20. ( A20, consisting of all even permutations, is a subgroup of the symmetric group S20).

But I guess that 2-SSG won't be a subset of A20, as there is a difference of factor 2.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the case that should have been excluded whereever you read the statement.